# MYSQL AVG by year

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table showing the daily sales:

```
CALENDAR   |         Sales
------ 
20170101   |           1
20170201   |           4
20170301   |           10
20170401   |           12

etc
```

How can I show the Daily sales per year?

The following query already produces monthly sales:

```
SELECT CALENDAR, AVG(sales)
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(CALENDAR), MONTH(CALENDAR)
HAVING COUNT(CALENDAR) = DAY(LAST_DAY(CALENDAR));
```

Comment: What is the intention of the HAVING clause?

Comment: What do you mean "Daily sales per year"? Can you show an example with  of the expected output?

Comment: The query is just a posible way to get to the output.

The expected output would be, over the year 2017 an average of 67 sales for example

Answer (score 1):

After some searching on the internet, this is the solution:

SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CALENDAR) AS 'Year', AVG(Sales)
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(CALENDAR)